# Combinatorics Question Regarding Specific Substring of Characters

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many strings of five lowercase letters from the Latin alphabet (containing 23 letters) contain:

- a) the letter *c*?
- b) the letters *c* and *d*?
- c) the letters *c* and *d* in consecutive position with *c* preceding *d* and all letters distinct?
- d) the letters *c* and *d*, where *c* is somewhere to the left of *d* in the string and all letters distinct?

---

I have already solved a) using $_5C_1\cdot23^4 =\frac{5!}{1!4!}\cdot23^4$ where one spot is *c* and the rest are any letter in the Latin alphabet, and b) $_5C_1\cdot_4C_1\cdot23^3 =\frac{5!}{1!4!}\cdot\frac{4!}{1!3!}\cdot23^3$ where one spot is *c*, one spot is *d* and the rest are any letter in the Latin alphabet since the letters are not distinct (repetition is allowed).

Now I am confused about how to account for the order of c and d in questions c) and d).  I know that I must now use $\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$ instead of $\frac{(n+r-1)!}{r!(n-1)!}$ since the letters are now distinct, but am lost from there.

Comment: First is not right, there has been some double-counting. The easiest way is to first count the strings that do not contain $c$.

Comment: I'm confused as to how there is double-counting here since the question is only looking for any string that contains the letter _c_, whether it is repeated or not.  Could you explain?

Comment: Your $\binom{5}{1}23^4$ counts cacaa twice, once as put c in first position and once as put c in third position. It also counts ccccc five times.

Comment: So a) would now be $23^5 - 22^5$ or strings with all letters of the alphabet - strings without _c_?

Comment: Yes, that is one answer for a).  A longer way is to count the words with $1$ c, $\binom{5}{1}22^4$. The words with $2$ c's,  $\binom{5}{2}22^3$. The words with $3$ c's, and so on and add up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

a) There are $22^5$ words that **do not** contain the letter c.

b) We count the words that miss c or d or both. There are $22^5$ words that do not contain c, and $22^5$ that do not contain d. But the sum $2\cdot 22^5$ double-counts the words that contain  neither c nor d. So there are $2\cdot 22^5-21^5$ words that are missing c or d or both.

c) The letter c can be in any of $4$ places. Once we have chosen where c is, the location of d is determined. And there are $(21)(20)(19)$ ways to fill the empty spots with letters distinct from c and d and from each other.

d) Put reserved signs on a couple of spots. This can be done in $\binom{5}{2}$ ways. The rest can be filled in $(21)(20)(19)$ ways.

Comment: Thank you very much André, you were very helpful.

Comment: You are welcome. That is my interpretation  of the purpose of MSE.  I was brief because I was confident you could fill in gaps.